# SafeArea color of bottom tab in dark mode cannot be changed

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-bottom-tab, safeareaview

I have been stuck in this issue since yesterday and I cannot find a solution.

I have been trying to adjust the color of safeArea in iPhone X, it's working well on the top, and in the bottom as well for screens with no tab, however, in screens with tab navigator, the bottom safeArea is always white as shown in the screenshot. Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Also, I want to ask if it would be better to use normal SafeAreaView component and remove the SafeAreaProvider and remove react-native-safe-area-context package, I just added it as a trial to solve this problem but I was first working with the react native normal SafeAreaView component;

In App component:

```
import { SafeAreaProvider } from "react-native-safe-area-context";
          <SafeAreaProvider>
            <NavigationContainer>
              <CatNavigator />
            </NavigationContainer>
          </SafeAreaProvider>
```

In the CatNavigator component:

```
const CatNavigator = () => {
  return (
    <Drawer.Navigator
      initialRouteName="Home"    >
      <Drawer.Screen
        name="Home"
        component={SettingsNavigator}
        options={{ title: "Inicio" }}
      />
    </Drawer.Navigator>
```

In the settings tab navigator:

```
const SettingsNavigator = () => {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator
      screenOptions={({ route }) => ({
        tabBarIcon: ({ focused, color, size }) => {
          let iconName;
          const iconType = Platform.OS === "ios" ? "ios" : "md";
          if (route.name === "Home") {
            iconName = iconType + "-home";
          } else if (route.name === "Settings") {
            iconName = iconType + "-settings";
          }
          const tabColor = focused ? Colors.buttonBackColor : Colors.titleColor;
          return <Ionicons name={iconName} size={size} color={color} />;
        },
      })}
      tabBarOptions={{
        activeTintColor: Colors.activeTabColor,
        inactiveTintColor: Colors.inactiveTabColor,
        activeBackgroundColor: Colors.tabBackgroundColor,
        inactiveBackgroundColor: Colors.tabBackgroundColor,
        safeAreaInset: { bottom: "never", top: "never" },
      }}
    >
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Home"
        component={HomeNavigator}
        options={{ title: "Inicio" }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Settings"
        component={SettingStackNavigator}
        options={{ title: "Ajustes" }}
      />
    </Tab.Navigator>
```

In SettingsNavigator:

```
const SettingStackNavigator = (props) => {
  return (
    <SettingStack.Navigator screenOptions={defaultNavOptions}>
      <SettingStack.Screen
        name="Settings"
        component={SettingScreen}
        options={settingsOptions}
      />
    </SettingStack.Navigator>
  );
};
```

And finally in SettingScreen:

```
import { SafeAreaView } from "react-native-safe-area-context";
    return (
      <SafeAreaView
        style={{
             flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: Colors.backgroundColor,
          justifyContent: "center",
          alignItems: "center",
        }}
      >
        {colorScheme === "dark" && <StatusBar barStyle="light-content" />}
       // Other components
      </SafeAreaView>
```

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to change that little guy at the bottoms color you need add the style option to your Tab.Navigator, like so

```
 tabBarOptions={{
    style: {
      backgroundColor: Colors.tabBackgroundColor,
    },
  }}
```

Comment: How does one accomplish the same thing on v6?

Comment: If someone receives a warning: `Bottom Tab Navigator: 'tabBarOptions' is deprecated.`, then add this: `tabBarStyle: [{ backgroundColor: Colors.tabBackgroundColor, }, null, ],` to your BottomTab Navigator's `screenOptions`.

Comment: not works for me